# Dynamic linker - how to find missing symbol

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, dynamic-linking

My program runs fine on OS X 10.6, but falters on 10.5 with the error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: 
__ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
```

Of course I don't have anything in my software that cryptic.

How do I go about figuring out what function I'm calling that isn't present on the libraries on 10.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `c++filt` command to figure out the name of the missing function.

In your case, it's `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)`

Answer (score 1):

As has been said by dasblinkenlight, `c++filt` is the command to use to decode "mangled names".

The issue seems to be that implementation details of the C++ library have probably changed with 10.6, and coode that uses the standard library and is compiled for 10.6 is just not compatible with 10.5.

I remember that Apple released the 10.3.9 update mostly to provide compatibility with programs compiled for 10.4.x; maybe they've done likewise for 10.5/10.6. Is your 10.5 system using the latest version?

If you want to be absolutely sure that your program runs on 10.5 even though you build it on 10.6, tell XCode to use the 10.5 SDK to build it.